# What's the proper way to process each member of an array?

Tags: arrays, swift3

Simple question:

How can I process each member (struct or scaler) of an array?

The following are two means of doing the same thing:

[image]

All I want to do is to process each member of an array.  But I can't figure out why 'num' must be a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num` is the *value* of each element, not a reference to the element. The correct way to map an array of values to a new array of values is with `map`:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array = array.map { $0 + 1 }
```

Among other benefits, this only sets `array` one time, so if `array` has `didSet` observers (which are more common on properties, but legal anywhere), then it would only be called one time.

You can modify the array one element at a time, but it is more awkward, less safe, requires more code, and has more side-effects (like executing `didSet` a bunch of times). That said, it occasionally can be useful. If so, you need to use subscripting.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
for index in array.indices {
    array[index] += 1
}
```

Comment: Worth noting.   I toyed with the 'map' and got it to work as well.  See answer.  I'll see if I can simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

I did discover the use of 'map' via a different pattern:

```
   func setColumnIDfor(matrixRow:inout[MatrixBox]) {

        let newMatrixRow = matrixRow.map { (box) -> MatrixBox in
            var tempBox = box
            tempBox.columnID = "Q"
            return tempBox
        }

        matrixRow = newMatrixRow

    }
```